# EditText inside a fragment is Hidden when soft keyboard opens

Tags: android

My Activity contains two fragments , at the bottom a control bar and above it this layout with two EditText:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/invested_grey_color" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@color/transperent_black" >

    <com.threefishmedia.sportzone.views.TextViewCustomFont
        android:id="@+id/choose_a_set_LeagueName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/view_tournament_rules"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/choose_a_set_view_tournamnet_rules_iv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/choose_a_set_LeagueName"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/question" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/Choose_a_set_rl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="@color/transperent_sportzone_green" >

    <com.threefishmedia.sportzone.views.TextViewCustomFont
        android:id="@+id/choose_a_set_stage_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/choose_a_set"
        android:textColor="@color/sportzone_green"
        android:textSize="35sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/choose_a_set_vi_sign_iv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/make_it_your_own"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Choose_a_set_rl"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:background="@color/transperent_sportzone_green" >

    <com.threefishmedia.sportzone.views.TextViewCustomFont
        android:id="@+id/make_it_your_own_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/make_it_your_own"
        android:textColor="@color/sportzone_green"
        android:textSize="35sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/add_tournament_name_ll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edit_text_wraper"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:background="@color/add_tournament_red_color"
    android:visibility="invisible" >

    <com.threefishmedia.sportzone.views.TextViewCustomFont
        android:id="@+id/information_to_user_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:text="@string/add_tournamnet_name"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/tournamnet_make_it_your_own_next_btn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/add_tournament_name_ll"
    android:background="@color/transperent_black"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:enabled="false" >

    <com.threefishmedia.sportzone.views.TextViewCustomFont
        android:id="@+id/make_iyt_your_own_next_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="@string/next"
        android:textColor="@color/disables_btn_text_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/next_btn_font" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/invite_friends_rl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tournamnet_make_it_your_own_next_btn"
    android:background="@color/transperent_sportzone_green" >

    <com.threefishmedia.sportzone.views.TextViewCustomFont
        android:id="@+id/invites_friends_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/invite_your_friends"
        android:textColor="@color/sportzone_green"
        android:textSize="35sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/edit_text_wraper"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/make_it_your_own" >

    <com.threefishmedia.sportzone.views.TextViewCustomFont
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/tournament_name"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tournament_name_et"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_et"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLength="30"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:textSize="30sp" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <com.threefishmedia.sportzone.views.TextViewCustomFont
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tournament_name_et"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tournament_name_et"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:text="@string/jeckpot"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/jeckpot_amont_et"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_et"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="9"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:textSize="35sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tournamentt_type_instructions_iv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/jeckpot_amont_et"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tournament_name_et"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/question" />

    <com.threefishmedia.sportzone.views.TextViewCustomFont
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tournamentt_type_instructions_iv"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="@string/tournament_type"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/basic_expert_switcher"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/jeckpot_amont_et"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/jeckpot_amont_et"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:textOff="@string/basic"
        android:textOn="@string/expert"
        android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_selector"
        android:track="@drawable/switch_bg" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

the problem is when the uses taps on the second EditText the keyboard hides it and the user can't see what he is typing. 
i worked on it for to long... i have added

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

and **adjustpan** in Manifest file , none of them helped.

any ideas?

Comment: Try seeting `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` to the `RelativeLayout`

Comment: put all the code in scrollview and then give android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Put this line inside oncreate,

```
 getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Comment: What finally worked for me was to put 
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
in the onCreateView of my fragment.  Just putting the code into the onCreate for the activity didn't work.  As I understand it, the activity's 'this' and the getActivity() in the fragment should be the same, but that didn't work   Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can also put this line on manifest

```
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
```

Comment: This solution does not work in this case. OP has mentioned he is using fragments in which case @Sreedhu Madhu's solution works.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem and adding this to the manifest worked for me.

```
<activity
    ...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation:

> `"adjustResize"`
>
> The activity's main window is always resized to make room for the soft
> keyboard on screen.
>
> `"adjustPan"`
>
> The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft
> keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned
> so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users
> can always see what they are typing. This is generally less desirable
> than resizing, because the user may need to close the soft keyboard to
> get at and interact with obscured parts of the window.

So inside a fragment you should use adjustPan in the manifest:

```
<activity
    ...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

Notice, that the keyboard will still hide the edittext, if the edittext is not currently focused (you are not typing inside of it.)